# Refresh list in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

From the view I'm sending users selected values to the controller which returns partial view.
This partial view is injected inside div on the same page which originaly sends request to the controller. Everything works as expected with one major issue. After data is received, jquery mobile unordered list items are lose it's styling.

I have html structure like this

```
<div class="divData" data-role="fieldcontain">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">

        <div id="filter">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model...})
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model...})
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model...})
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
    <div id="divMyData">
       <div id="details">
          <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="" data-inset="true">
            @{        
               foreach (var d in Model)
               {             
                  <li><a onclick="processData('@d.Id')">@d.Id</a></li> 
               }
            }
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js function

```
success: function (result)
{
   $("#divMyData").html(result);
   // I've tried to refresh list like but without succ.
   $("#details").listview("refresh");       
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#details` is not the ID of your list. It is the ID of the DIV that contains the list.  You can either assign an ID to the list and call listview('refresh') on that or:

```
$("#details ul").listview("refresh");
```

> **UPDATE:**

Looking at your success code, you are completely replacing the details div and ul and not just appending listitems.  In this case listview('refresh') will not work because you have blown away and recreated the listview.

Instead try initializing the listview:

```
$("#details ul").listview();
```

If that does not work, call `enhanceWithin()` (http://api.jquerymobile.com/enhanceWithin/) on the container:

```
$("#divMyData").html(result).enhanceWithin();
```

NOTE: enhanceWithin is for jQM 1.4.x, for previous versions you would need `.trigger("create")`

Comment: thanks for your time, tried but it doesnt work. Once more, When ul list items initially set those are correctly styled but after callback from controller this jquery mob. style are removed.

Comment: @user1765862, see my updated answer. That should work for you.